# Rails 5 - how to sort data based on data in another table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have these models:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_documents
end
class ProductDocument < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I want to list ALL products AND sort them based on the attribute `product_documents.doc_type = 1` (note: some products don't have uploaded any documents, some have N).

I tried something like this:

```
@products = Product.joins(:product_documents)
                      .where('product_documents.doc_type = ?', 1)
                      .order('product_documents.doc_url')
                      .page(params[:page]).per(50)
```

But this query returns me only those products that have uploaded a document with `doc_type=1`.

How do I list all products (even those where is no document with `doc_type=1`) and sort them by the fact if they have uploaded a document with `doc_type=1`?

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic idea, you can have a [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html) statement in your SQL order by clause (at least if you're using Postgres). If `doc_type=1` then in orders them first, everything else goes after that, then you can order by other columns.

```
Product.joins(:product_documents)
.order("
  CASE product_documents.doc_type
    WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  product_documents.doc_url
")
```

Comment: This is not tested, so there may be tweaks to be done ....

Answer (score 1):

You are using `where` but you want `sort`. Use the below code:

```
@products = Product.joins(:product_documents)
                      .order('product_documents.doc_type asc')
                      .order('product_documents.doc_url')
                      .page(params[:page]).per(50)
```

`where` is used to **filter** the data. `order` is used to **sort** the data.

**The above code will **sort** the records based on `doc_type` and `doc_url`.**

If you dont want to order by **doc_url**, you can remove that code.

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible to do it all in one query, it would become nearly impossible to get good performance out of it once the tables grow large (which is why you're paginating, right?) because it's really two different types of queries.

### Live Query

In Rails, those two queries would be:

```rb
products_without_one = Product.where.not('EXISTS (?)',
  ProductDocument.where('products.id = product_documents.product_id').where(doc_type: 1).select(1)
)
products_with_one = Product.joins(:product_documents).where(product_documents: { doc_type: 1 }).distinct
```

You *could* `UNION` the results together, but most of the time you'll be paging through only one of the two queries before you start paging through the other.

If you *really* want to do it in a single query, or if your tables aren't going to grow really big, then do:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON(p.id) p.id, doc_type
  FROM products p
  LEFT JOIN product_documents pd ON pd.product_id = p.id
  ORDER BY p.id ASC, doc_type DESC
) sub
ORDER BY doc_type
```

### Cache Column

If you need to run these queries frequently and quickly, I suggest changing the data being queried. Adding a new column to `Product` that's like:

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :primary_doc_one, class_name: ProductDocument.to_s
end

# making the query:
Product.order_by('primary_doc_one_id NULLS FIRST') # or LAST
```

or

```rb
# with a Product#num_doc_type_one column
Product.order_by(:num_doc_type_one)
```

Though you'll have to make sure you maintain these columns properly with transactions and such (avoid callbacks if you can).

#### Misc

I've omitted the `.order('product_documents.doc_url')` because it doesn't really make sense. If a `Product` has many `ProductDocument`, which `doc_url` should be used when sorting? e.g. given:

```
product_documents
id | product_id | doc_url
-------------------------
1  |      1     |   'A'
2  |      1     |   'C'
3  |      2     |   'B'
```

(ignoring `doc_type`) should the output of `Product` be:

```
{ product_id: 1, doc_url: 'A' }
{ product_id: 2, doc_url: 'B' }
```

or

```
{ product_id: 2, doc_url: 'B' }
{ product_id: 1, doc_url: 'C' }
```

Comment: thanks for your effort. After some playing around, I decided to move that column to the `Product` model.